# Some problems to understand CSS paged media style

Tags: html, css, xhtml, css-paged-media

I have some doubt about the paged media in CSS.

If I have something like this code:

```
@page rotated {size: landscape}
TABLE {page: rotated; page-break-before: right}
```

what exactly happen? can you explain to me this code? I am reading the documentation but I am finding some problems...

Tnx
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a rule that apply while printing, if the browser encounters a  element in your document and the current page layout is the default portrait layout, it starts a new page and prints the table on a landscape page.